# PHP Seo Friendly URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I'm having some trouble using rewrite engine to achieve my goal with friendly url.

Basically I have the following structure:
- index.php
  - down
  - index.php

My links in main index are something like this:
download/index.php?down=FILENAME

I would like it to rewrite something like
/download/FILE-NAME ( while pointing for the index.php inside download folder ).
I would like my links in first index could be used as well /download/FILE-NAME

My actual code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule download/^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?down=$1
```

Can anyone help me achieving this? I'm constantly getting error due to I can't do it right.
After that, how can I get the the variable $1 after transform to seo friendly urls? I will have download/FILE-NAME and I need with PHP get the info from FILE-NAME.

So basically in the main index.php I would have a link like /download/FILE-NAME that will open the down/index.php file with the FILE-NAME ( staying something like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^download/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?down=$1 [L,QSA]
```

to catch filename in index.php:

```
$filename = $_GET["down"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^download/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /ifanydirectory/index.php?down=$1
```

And you can get variable using `$_GET['down']` `ifanydirectory` is the directory name in which `index.php` exists relative path from root level, if not applicable simply use `/index.php` 
do some experiments you'll get the correct one.

Comment: After use it it doesn't work. After that I can't access main index.php receiving a Forbidden error.

Comment: Use relative path to index.php like RewriteRule ^download/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?down=$1 add any directory name after / or simply leave it like /index.php

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I've not explain it well because it doesn't work as it's supposed.

I've edited the main question but try to explain better here.

I have a main index.php with links that would be

```
download/FILE-1
download/FILE-2
download/FILE-3
```

That links should open the folder **down/index.php?down=FILE-NAME**.
Isn't supposed that anyone can access "down" folder directly, so I would like to transform links in my main index.php like /down/index.php?down=FILE-NAME to something like /download/FILE-NAME.